# How to see exactly what the Signal R request in Blazor is? My message is too large and I can't figure out why

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am getting the following error message:

```
Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error. InvalidDataException: The maximum message size of 36000B was exceeded. The message size can be configured in AddHubOptions.'.
Uncaught Error Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error. InvalidDataException: The maximum message size of 36000B was exceeded. The message size can be configured in AddHubOptions.
```

Astute readers will notice that I already increased the maximum message size. I could increase it again, but that does not fix the problem. I want to know why the message is so large in the first place.

However I cannot track down exactly which message is triggering this message. In Chrome dev tools I can see the error in binary but not what caused it. I enabled more logging and that also gives me the error but not the source of the error.

How do I see exactly what is causing this large message?

Comment: If anyone is reading this in the future, I had too many parameters going into a component. Once I combined them all into an object and passed that in instead the error went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I see exactly what is causing this large message?

You can network trace by the way:

**Collect a network trace with Fiddler**
Install it from [telerik.com/fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), launch it, and then run your app

[image]

For more info you can refer to [Network traces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-6.0#network-traces)

You can trace your web socket by `wireshark` too. It's a [sample video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5R1ugZ_jLDI).

> but that does not fix the problem
> Please

Please also try the following codes:

```
services.AddSignalR(o => {
                    o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = null; // no limit
                    o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                }).AddMessagePackProtocol();


services.Configure<HubOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = null;
});




public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
{
    ....
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

     app.UseEndpoints(routes => {
     
        routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub", options =>
        {
            options.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = 1024000;
            // Set to 0 for no limit, or to some non-zero value (in bytes) to set a different buffer limit
            options.TransportMaxBufferSize = 0;
        });
    });
    
    app.UseMvc();
    ....
}
```